# How to solve error "connection:closed" in SharePoint2010?

Tags: iis-7, sharepoint-2007, sitecollection

> Hi , when i deleted site under mysite collection the webapplication
>   doesnot work and i had this error
>
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5 Date: Fri, 13 Dec 2013
>   07:03:54 GMT Connection: close
>
> When I checked the log file I had this :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Microsoft [support page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2770732)

**Cause**

> This is caused by insufficient permissions for the search service account on the SharePoint Server. Verify that no group policies have been set on the local user groups 'WSS_WPG' and 'WSS_ADMIN_WPG'.

**Resolution**

> Check the system event log for group policy changes that may have occurred around the same time as the search errors. Determine if any group policies have altered permissions on 'WSS_WPG', or WSS_ADMIN_WPG groups

From the folder *%COMMONPROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\14\bin* run the Psconfig command-line tool for SharePoint Products as follows:

```
Psconfig -cmd secureresources
```